# Derivative of reparametrization

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, derivative

I am stuck in one equation when reading the paper. Regardless of the context, here is the question:
Let's say given an equation L($\sigma_g^2$, $\sigma_\epsilon^2$, $\beta$) = ....
Now I want to use $\delta = \frac{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{\sigma_g^2}$ to reparametrize the equation so that it becomes $L(\sigma_g^2, \delta, \beta) = ....$

Now my question is, suppose I want to take the derivative of $L(\sigma_g^2, \delta, \beta)$ with respect to $\sigma_g^2$, do I need to use the chain rule to also take the derivative of $\sigma_g^2$ with respect to $\delta$?

To make it concrete, here is what the paper writes:
This is the reparametrization I refers to:
[image]

And here is the maximum likelihood function of the above $LL(\delta, \sigma_g^2, \beta)$:

[image]

Now I want to take the derivative of the above function with respect to $\sigma_g^2$:
[image]

Based on the equation, the derivative of $\sum_{i=1}^nlog([S]_{ii} + \delta)$ with respect to $\sigma_g^2$ is 0. But $\delta$ is a function of $\sigma_g^2$, which doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone explain the reason?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the *partial derivative*, not the *total derivative*, although seemingly doesn't say it explicitly. Partial derivative assumes that the parameters other than the one being differentiated are constant. Intuitively, the reparametrization is an axis change. Now the log-likelihood is plotted against $(x,y,z)=(\sigma_g^2,\delta,\beta)$ instead of $(x,y,z)=(\sigma_g^2,\sigma_e^2,\beta)$. We can always find a $\delta$ to satisfy a desired level of $\sigma_e^2$, no information is lost. But, it's normal for the partial derivative to change because we actually assume that $\delta,\beta$ are constant while we change $\sigma_g^2$, which means that we are actually changing $\sigma_e^2$ simultaneously while keeping $\delta$ constant, under the hood.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, may I know which piece of knowledge does this come from?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question, can you open up a bit?

Comment: I know even in partial derivative, you can't always treat other parameters other than the one you want to differentiate ($\sigma_g^2$) to be constant unless the other parameters are either independent to ($\sigma_g^2$) or dependent on ($\sigma_g^2$)  but have degree of freedom > 1 (like $\delta$). I wonder which property or reparametrization trick does it comes from, I want to learn further and get a better understanding of the reparametrization trick. Thank you!